# AWS API Gateway adding Content-Type Header to OPTIONS Reques

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, preflight

I am trying to write an OPTIONS request using a Lambda and AWS Gateway to respond to post requests - this code comes from AWS documentation:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var responseCode = 200;

    var response = {
        statusCode: responseCode,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    };

    context.succeed(response);
};
```

When I test it in AWS Lambda, it provides the correct response

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run it using AWS API Gateway,
 it adds on a Content-Type header that was not part of the response.  As a result, when I tried to make a post requests, I get the error that 'Content Type in not allowed in preflight response'.  Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

if you run the below command,

```
curl -H "origin: example.com" -v "https://h64hstwg05.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/optionsrequest"
```

it returns `content-type: application/json`. it is because `application/json` is the default value when it is not specified.

here is this from aws docs.

> When the Content-Type header is absent in the request, API Gateway assumes that its default value is application/json

Reference:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html

You could always override and return a different `content-type` header from the lambda.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the answer satisfy you. Please approve the answer if so.

Comment: This is correct, however the question is why AWS is forcing a content-type header on an OPTIONS request.  It should be possible to return the response without a content-type header, as simply having this header is causing an error with the preflight request.

Comment: Lets us know if you ever find out why AWS is forcing the content-type to be JSON